# How to define method names and object references before actually having to use them (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, methods

Say I am keeping track of email correspondances. An enquiry (from a customer) or a reply (from a supporter) is embedded in the order the two parties are corresponding about. They share the exact same logic when put into the database.

My problem is that even though I use the same logic, the object classes are different, the model fields I need to call are different, and the method names are different as well.

How do I put methods and objects references in before I actually have to use them? Does a "string_to_method" method exists or something like that?

Sample code with commentaries:

```
class Email
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :from, type: String
  field :to, type: String
  field :subject, type: String

  belongs_to :order, :inverse_of => :emails

  def start
    email = Email.create!(:from => "sender@example.com", :to => "recipient@example.com", :subject => "Hello")

    from_or_to = from                  # This represents the database field from where I later on will fetch the customers email address. It is either from or to.
    enquiries_or_replies = enquiries   # This represents a method that should later be called. It is either enquiries or replies.

    self.test_if_enquiry_or_reply(from_or_to, enquiries_or_replies)
  end

  def test_if_enquiry_or_reply(from_or_to, enquiries_or_replies)
    order = Order.add_enquiry_or_reply(self, from_or_to, enquiries_or_replies)
    self.order = order
    self.save
  end
end

class Order
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :email_address, type: String

  has_many :emails, :inverse_of => :order
  embeds_many :enquiries, :inverse_of => :order
  embeds_many :replies, :inverse_of => :order

  def self.add_enquiry_or_reply(email, from_or_to, enquiries_or_replies)
    order = Order.where(:email_address => email.from_or_to).first  # from_or_to could either be from or to.
    order.enquiries_or_replies.create!(subject: email.subject)     # enquiries_or_replies could either be enquiries or replies.
    order
  end
end
```

Comment: I think you may be trying to shove too much into your order model. Unless you can give a specific example regarding the code duplication (it's best to show it long form with the duplication), it may be hard to help. And with Ruby there's probably 100 ways to do it each with different trade offs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the question and the code sample, it sounds like you are mixing concerns too much. My first suggestion would be to re-evaluate your method names and object structure. Ambiguous names like `test_if_thing1_or_thing2` and `from_or_to` (it should just be one thing) will make it very hard for others, and your future self, to understand the code laster.

However, without diverging into a debate on separation of concerns, you can change the methods you call by using [`public_send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-public_send) (or the private aware [`send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-send)). So you can do

```rb
order.public_send(:replies).create!

order.public_send(:enquiries).create!
```

Answer (score 0):

string to method does exist, it's called `eval`

so, you could do

```
method_name = "name"
eval(method_name) #calls the name method
```